# Webapp Substrate script for WordPress on Debian-Nginx

Tags: bash, linux, wordpress, installer, nginx

The following script creates a webapp substrate for *WordPress* webapps/websites on *Ubunu*-*Nginx* with *PHP-FPM* and *Mysql* environments, with Certbot, while all software is uncustomized.

Such substrate includes, based on the 1 or more domains given as an argument (
`/opt/nwsm.sh domain1.tld domain2.tld`):

1. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf`.
2. `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` symlink.
3. Appropriate DB user and instance, named `example.com`.
4. Suitable `wp-config.php` file.

I especially hope to learn how I could **shorten** this code in at least 10 rows, if at all.

### Installing the script

Just copy and paste in Bash and it willl be created under `/opt/nwsm.sh`.

```sh
cat <<-"NWSM" > /opt/nwsm.sh
    #!/bin/sh
    for domain; do
        cat <<-WEBAPPCONF > "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf" 
            server {
                root /var/www/html/${domain};
                server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
                location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
                    expires 365d; 
                }
                location / {
                    index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
                    try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }
                location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                }
            }
        WEBAPPCONF
        ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

        echo "Please enter database user password for user ${domain}: "
        read -s waps
        echo "Please enter database root password"
        mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
            create user "${domain}"@"localhost" identified by "${waps}";
            create database ${domain};
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO ${domain}@localhost;
        MYSQL

        certbot --nginx -d ${domain} -d www.${domain}
    done

    cd /var/www/html/
    wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
    tar xzvf latest.tar.gz && rm latest.tar.gz
    mv wordpress ${domain}

    cp /var/www/html/${domain}/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/${domain}/wp-config.php
    echo "1/1: Please enter the password of the site's DB user." && read -s dbup
    sed -i "s/database_name_here/${domain}"/g /var/www/html/${domain}/wp-config.php
    sed -i "s/username_here/${domain}"/g /var/www/html/${domain}/wp-config.php
    sed -i "s/password_here/${dbup}"/g /var/www/html/${domain}/wp-config.php

    chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/* -R
    find /var/www/html/* -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    find /var/www/html/* -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    systemctl restart nginx.service
NWSM
chmod +x /opt/nwsm.sh
```

### Using the script

Call the script with a domain and tld as an argument, say:

```
/opt/nwsm.sh example.com
```

Comment: Why start by with `cat <<-"NWSM" > /opt/nwsm.sh` which will fail when run on a machine that doesn't have opt, or by a user that doesn't have write permissions to it?

Comment: This mistake is because there I put all my scripts. What other dir do you recommend?

Comment: To start with, I'd recommend not using a heredoc to create the script; just let the person who's testing your scripts put them where they like.
As for directory, I'd probably use a subdirectory somewhere - which one would depend on the general filesystem layout. Possible candidates could be `/root/bin`, `/opt/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/scripts`, `/home/jenny/bin`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The outer heredoc construct isn't really required.
- You do not verify that you have command line arguments.
- You do not assign your command line arguments to the variable `domain`.
- You use the variable `domain` when it is uninitialised.

You make a number of assumptions, any one of which could bite you hard.

- You assume that the nginx package has been installed and that it has created the paths and other things you require.
- You assume that the MySQL packages have been installed.
- You assume that the certbot package has been installed.
- You assume that the `/var/www/html` directory exists.
- You assume that the `www-data` user exists.
- You assume that this is the first time that the script has been run for `domain`. It will have unexpected results if `domain` already exists.

Think about those assumptions and what would happen if they were incorrect and things didn't exist as you expect.

Your variable names are not good - why, for example, is the database user's password assigned to `waps` and not something like `dbpassword`?

It's not clear if you are planning on passing more than one domain to the script per invocation. If you only plan one domain per invocation you do not need the `for loop`.

You assume that all of your commands will complete correctly. You really should check the exit status of those that could reasonably be expected to fail. For example the `wget` could fail for many reasons. If it does then everything after it should not be run. What happens if `certbot` fails or `mysql` or `tar` or ...

Your `chown -R...` command assumes that nothing else is installed in /var/www/html or that everything installed there should be owned by www-data, this may not be the case, use `/var/www/html/${domain}`. Your `find` commands are the same.

Your `find` commands will exec `chmod` for every file found. It is more efficient to use `find ... -exec {} +` which optimises the size of the command line and reduces the number of execs.

> I especially hope to learn how I could shorten this code in at least 10 rows, if at all.

How sweet, I can see it being considerably larger.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71637/discussion-on-answer-by-user157887-webapp-substrate-script-for-wordpress-on-debi).